# 'Deadlock' in scala

Tags: scala, actor

I want to rewrite in scala the example from Sun's tutorial about concurrency in java. The original code is here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

This code is incorrect. It freezes at where the comment indicates. Could anyone correct this? Thanks in advance.

```
import scala.actors.Actor

class Person(val name: String) extends Actor {

  def bow(other: Person) {
    other ! Bow(this)
  }

  private def bowBack(backTo: Person) {
    println(this.name + " is bowing back to " + backTo.name)
    backTo ! Bowed(this)
  }

  def act() {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case Bow(p) =>
          println(this.name + " is bowing to " + p.name)
          p ! BowBack(this)
          println("    wating for bowing back...")
          var received = false
          while (true && received == false) {
            receive {    //blocked here
              case Bowed(other) if p == other =>
                println(" ... " + this.name + " has bowed to " + other.name)
            received == true
            }
          }
          println(this.name + " has bowed to " + p.name)
        case BowBack(p) =>
          println(this.name + " is bowing back to " + p.name)
          p ! Bowed(this)
        case "EXIT" => return
        case x => println(x)
      }
    }
  }
}

abstract case class Action()
case class Bow(person: Person) extends Action
case class BowBack(person: Person) extends Action
case class Bowed(person: Person) extends Action

object BowTest extends Application {
  val a = new Person("Alphone")
  val g = new Person("Gaston")
  a.start()
  g.start()

  a ! Bow(g)
  //g.bow(a)

  a ! "EXIT"
  g ! "EXIT"
}
```

Comment: Can reduce the amount of code to the absolute minimum which is necessary to reproduce the deadlock ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first mistake is that you wrote `result == true`. This should be changed to `result = true`

You should delete the `true` value from the while condition. It has no influence.

In the `BowTest` object you should add after the `g.bow(a)` instruction `Thread.sleep(1000)` to give actors enough time to respond to the messages.

In this way your code should work. But still it has a deadlock. If you will change `g.bow(a)` in `a.bow(g)` the execution will freeze. This is caused by the `receive` block. Each actor is waiting for the Bowed message, but they cannot respond to the BowBack message.

When you are responding to a message, you should use `receive` block only if you are sure that the actor will get the specified messages. But usually this is not a good practice in designing actors. They should not block. The main purpose of an actor is to respond as fast as possible to a message. If you have to do a big task you should use `futures`, but in this case is not required.

A solution will be to retain the persons which are bowed in a list. When the actor have to bow a person it adds it in the list. When the actor is bowed by a person which is in the list, it removes that person from the list.

```
    while (true) {
      react {
        case Bow(p) =>
          println(this.name + " is bowing to " + p.name)
          addPersonToBowList(p)
          p ! BowBack(this)

        case Bowed(other) if isPersonInBowList(other) =>
                println(" ... " + this.name + " has bowed to " + other.name)
                removePersonFromBowList(other)
        case BowBack(p) =>
          println(this.name + " is bowing back to " + p.name)
          p ! Bowed(this)
        case "EXIT" => exit()
        case x => println(x)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Well you certainly went a lot further than I did with my answer!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed a solution. The code pasted here is somewhat messy, because I'm tuning it.

Comment: To fully simulating this kind of interaction seems to lead to a much more complicated model.

Answer (score 0):

Not deadlock, just a plain ol' bug, I think. Two lines under your comment:

`received == true`

This should be `=` instead of `==`. I've not looked in depth (this sprung out at me) but it *looks* like this would fix your issue.